# Error Syntax error: Expected end of input but got "(" at [19:10]

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, syntax-error

I hope you all are fine. I am doing an exercise in the Google Data Analysis certification, this is the exercise:

**A bike-share company has reached a recent milestone, and their marketing team wants to write a blog post that “congratulates” their most-used bike on being so popular. They want to include the name of the station that the bike is most likely to be found.**

**They task you with figuring out the station from which the bike begins a trip most frequently.
In order to do this, you will need to create a temp table to find the ID number of the bike that has taken the longest total trips (in minutes). You will take a sum of the minutes of each trip for each bike, then sort by descending order to find the bike that has spent the most minutes being used.**

What I am doing is this, but BigQuery tells me that there is a syntax error that I do not understand, I am a very noob data analyst, LOL. Could you help me to see what is wrong? Please!

```
WITH 
    longest_used_bike AS (
        SELECT 
            bikeid,
            SUM(duration_minutes) AS trip_duration
        FROM 
            bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips
        GROUP BY 
            bikeid
        ORDER BY 
            trip_duration DESC 
        LIMIT 1
    )
```

[And this is how this part looks in the exercise (they are helping me, XD)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39FUW.png)

Now, until here we just created a temporary table, where we have the most used bike in the system, now we need to know what is the most used station by this particular bike because this is where we should go to search it!

To do this, we need to do an INNER JOIN, where having the bike ID in the temporary table that we just created seconds ago, we can know the most used station by this bike, so this is the code:

```
##find station at which the longest-used bike leaves most often 
SELECT 
    trips.start_station_id
    COUNT(*)
FROM 
    longest_used_bike AS longest
INNER JOIN 
    bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips AS trips
    ON longest.bikeid = trips.bikeid
GROUP BY 
    trips.start_station_id
ORDER BY 
    trip_ct DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

[And this is how all the code should looks like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Spl91.png)

But, for some reason in my BigQuery, it tells me: ***Error Syntax error: Expected end of input but got "(" at [19:10]***

[It looks like the syntax error is in the COUNT function of the SELECT after the temporary table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h13Dp.png)

Could you please help me?! I don´t know what is wrong and I want to learn how to solve this problem and avoid more headaches in the future, LOL

Comment: You are missing a comma on the previous line.  I'm voting to close as a typo.

Comment: `SELECT trips.start_station_id` ***-> `,` <-*** `COUNT(*)`

Comment: Doesn't `bigquery-public-data` need to be delimited? I read it as bigquery minus public minus data.

Comment: In SQL, comments are usually marked with `--` rather than `#`

Comment: Really, a comma?! I am feeling like a dumbass, thank you for your help, LOL. It turns out that it was just a comma, I cannot believe it, but thank you again. I will start comments with -- in the future, thank you all, and bye!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct script that could run successfully. You can figure out your errors by comparison.

```sql
WITH longest_used_bike AS(SELECT 
      bikeid,

      SUM(duration_minutes) AS trip_duration
      FROM 
      bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips
     GROUP BY bikeid
     ORDER BY  trip_duration DESC 
     LIMIT 1
)
## find station at which longest bikeshare ride started

SELECT 
    trips.start_station_id,
COUNT(*) AS trip_ct
FROM 
    longest_used_bike AS longest
INNER JOIN 
`bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips` AS trips

ON 
longest.bikeid=trips.bikeid

GROUP BY 
      trips.start_station_id
ORDER BY 
     trip_ct DESC 
     LIMIT 1
```