# Trying to solve a Coursera problem and keep getting syntax error

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, syntax-error

I am trying to complete this query in Bigquery but continue to get syntax error. What am I doing wrong??? I have looked at others solutions and I can't locate why I am unable to get the query to run.

```
WITH longest_used_bike AS 
(
    SELECT 
        bikeid,
        SUM(duration_minutes) AS trip_duration
    FROM
        bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips
    GROUP BY
        bikeid
    ORDER BY
        trip_duration DESC
    LIMIT 1 
)
```

Comment: I guess, you need to use your longest_used_bike, something like SELECT * FROM longest_used_bike

Comment: It'd be helpful to see the exact error you're getting, but if what you've posted above is the entirety of your script, you'd need to add something after the CTE to consume it. I.e. after the closing parenthesis, "SELECT * FROM longest_used_bike"

Comment: did you read this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73118829/big-query-syntax-issue or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72653534/coursera-query-returning-select-list-expression-references-trips-start-station or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67705143/error-syntax-error-expected-end-of-input-but-got-at-1910 or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67869254/syntax-error-expected-or-or-keyword-select-but-got-end-of-script ?

Comment: @JeffreyVanLaethem Syntax error: Unexpected end of script at [13:3]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with a second select to consume your cte and Limit 1 outside :

```
 WITH longest_used_bike AS
    (
      SELECT 
        bike_id,
        SUM(duration_minutes) AS trip_duration
      FROM 
        `bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips` 
      GROUP BY
        bike_id
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM longest_used_bike
    ORDER BY trip_duration DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```